# Power Spectrum (Conjugate Matrix Multiplication) in Matlab : Getting complex values instead of real ones. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix-multiplication

Here's my code, so simple that I can't believe it doesn't work.

```
pckint = imread('pckint.jpg');
F = fft2(pckint);
Fcon = conj(F);
S = F*Fcon;
```

Now, as per the assignment directions, and my understanding of the subject, I should get real values in my power spectrum 'S'. However, I am getting complex values.

I am sorry I am a complete noob when it comes to Matlab, but I have tried searching and understanding all the commands I have used but to no avail. Please help!

Comment: I think you mean element-wise multiplication between `F` and `Fconj`; see [the wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_correlation). You are doing matrix multiplication, which only works if you have a square image (my test was with a rectangular image, in which case it failed) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply elementwise multiplication so that (i,j)th element is multiplied with (i,j)th element:

```
S = F.*Fcon;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean element-wise multiplication between `F` and `Fconj`; see the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_correlation).

You are doing *matrix* multiplication, which only works if you have a square image; when I first tried, my test was with a rectangular image, so I instantly saw why it was incorrect :)

Have a read on [the various operators in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operators.html).

Just try this:

```
pckint = imread('pckint.jpg');
F = fft2(pckint);    
S = F.*conj(F);

any(imag(S(:)) ~= 0)
```

Result:

```
ans = 
       0
```